# My own domain showing up in the Serpstat "Competitors in organic search" report

Tags: search-results, serpstats

Is it normal to see my own domain (created as a project in Serpstat) to show up in the "Competitors in organic search" report?

Comment: do you have multiple versions of your site? like www and non www. If you don't have one version it can happen.

Comment: I'm not sure. This is my website - www.mysoftinn.com

We made our server reachable by both www and non-www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common.   It seems to be the way that Serpstats works.   I just checked half a dozen sites and every single one of them was listed as its own competitor.   Here is a screenshot of the report for "stackexchange.com":

[image]

I'm not sure how they order that chart.   It appears they *always* put your own site at the top of that list.   For example, here is a screenshot of the report for "stackoverflow.com" which was listed as the #4 competitor for Stack Exchange:

[image]